# Dynamically add/remove rows and columns

Tags: javascript

I'd like to realize dynamic addition of a `div` block. That `div` block will be a square. When you click to add the horizontal will be adding a new square, and when you click on a vertical. But the question is, if I added a 5 squares horizontally, what would  add the square of the vertical it must be filled with another 4 horizontally squares around.

**[Jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/shift_break/L89upjae/7/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckemauaL/)

```js
function addCol() {
 var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var square = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("square")[0];
  var newSquare = square.cloneNode(true);
  rows[i].appendChild(newSquare);
 }
 
 var delCol = document.getElementById("delCol");
 var squares = rows[0].getElementsByClassName("square");
 delCol.style.marginLeft = 4 + (squares.length * 52) + "px";
}

function addRow() {
 var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
 var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
 var newRow = rows[0].cloneNode(true);
 grid.appendChild(newRow);
 
 var delRow = document.getElementById("delRow");
 delRow.style.marginTop = 2 + (rows.length-1) * 52 + "px";
}

function delCol() {
 var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  rows[i].removeChild(rows[i].lastChild);
 }
 
 var delCol = document.getElementById("delCol");
 var marginLeft = parseInt(getComputedStyle(delCol).marginLeft, 10);
 delCol.style.marginLeft = marginLeft - 52 + "px";
}

function delRow() {
 var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
 grid.removeChild(grid.lastChild);
 
 var delRow = document.getElementById("delRow");
 var marginTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(delRow).marginTop, 10);
 delRow.style.marginTop = marginTop - 52 + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
#container {
 overflow: auto;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
}
#delCol {
 margin-left: 56px;
}
#delRow {
}
.delWrapper {
 overflow: auto;
}
#delColContainer {
 clear: both;
}
#delRowContainer {
 display: table;
 float: left;
}
#gridWrapper {
 display: table;
 float: left;
}
#grid {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid #4dabe4;
}
.row {
 overflow: auto;
}
.square {
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: #4dabe4;
 margin: 1px;
}
.controls {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: .75;
}
.controls:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.controls.add {
 background: #f1a417;
 float: left;
}
.controls.del {
 background: #b00100;
 float: left;
}
.controls p {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}
#addRow {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="delWrapper" id="delColContainer">
        <div class="controls del" id="delCol" onclick="delCol()">
            <p>-</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="delWrapper" id="delRowContainer">
        <div class="controls del" id="delRow" onclick="delRow()">
            <p>-</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gridWrapper">
        <div id="grid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="square">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls add" id="addCol" onclick="addCol()">
            <p>+</p>
        </div>
        <div class="controls add" id="addRow" onclick="addRow()">
            <p>+</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

[**OLD (fiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/5hdjc2aa/)

```js
function addCol() {
  var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var square = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("square")[0];
    var copy = square.cloneNode(true);
    rows[i].appendChild(copy);
  }
}

function addRow() {
  var main = document.getElementById("main");
  var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
  var copy = rows[0].cloneNode(true);
  main.appendChild(copy);
}
```

```css
.index {
  display: table;
}
#main {
  float: left;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #4dabe4;
}
.square {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4dabe4;
  margin: 1px;
}
.controls {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f1a417;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .75;
}
.controls:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.controls p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#addRow {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <div id="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="square">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls" id="addCol" onclick="addCol()">
    <p>+</p>
  </div>
  <div class="controls" id="addRow" onclick="addRow()">
    <p>+</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to remove elements except the first one?

Comment: @MarcoRoys Updated the answer. Now you can both add and remove cells.